# How to design this tables better?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Firstly, sorry about the title I couldn't find better one.

I have a database that stores some devices depending on their number:

```
|-----------|-------------|-------------|
| device_id | device_name | device_type |
|-----------|-------------|-------------|
```

Each device has two types, **3-port** and  **1-port** and each port has specific name, for example:

- Device 1122   is type 3-port, port names are (kitchen,
  living_room, bed_room).
- Device 1123  is type 1-port, port name is (boiler).

My imagination design is:

```
|-----------|-------------|--------|-----------|--------|
+ device_id | device_name | port_1 |  port_2   | port_3 +
|-----------|-------------|--------|-----------|--------|
| 1122      | First floor | kitchen|living_room|bed_room|
|-----------|-------------|--------|-----------|--------|
| 1123      | Second floor| boiler | null      | null   |
|-----------|-------------|--------|-----------|--------|
```

But my design is not good since if I had 100 device of type **1-port** I leave 200 fields empty. 
Can you please help me to create better design ?

Comment: You could break out ports to a separate, normalized table with deviceId, port number, and port name. You will have one record for each device and port combination with a foreign key reference back to the main devices table. This will reduce empty fields and allow more than 3 ports should the requirements change.  However this comes at the cost of an additional table and duplication of the key.  From a space perspective you may not end up much better.  Then again, storage is pretty cheap so I would not sweat it too much.

Comment: @BJSafdie: Thanks, I think it's better than my solution since reduces some space and it's more academic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pasting in my comment as an answer so you can mark the question answered.

> You could break out ports to a separate, normalized table with
>   deviceId, port number, and port name. You will have one record for
>   each device and port combination with a foreign key reference back to
>   the main devices table. This will reduce empty fields and allow more
>   than 3 ports should the requirements change. However this comes at the
>   cost of an additional table and duplication of the key. From a space
>   perspective you may not end up much better. Then again, storage is
>   pretty cheap so I would not sweat it too much.

Zohar's answer is much more complete, so I will not have a problem if you accept his answer.  However you should accept an answer to close the question.

Comment: I will accept this answer since it's much simpler. Thanks BJ.

Answer (score 2):

A fully normalized schema will have device type table (where you specify the number of ports for each device type),
a device table with a unique device name and device id,
a ports table with a unique port name and a unique port id,
and an intersection table with device id and port id where the combination of these 2 columns is the primary key.
You should consider adding a check constraint on adding records to the intersection table to make sure you don't add too many records according to the device type (if your target db supports check constraints).

Here is a pseudo code for this schema:

```
TblDeviceType
(
    DeviceType_Id int, -- primary key
    DeviceType_Name varchar(20) -- unique
)

TblDevice
(
    Device_Id int, -- primary key
    Device_Type int, -- fk to TblDeviceType
)

TblPorts
(
    Port_Id int, -- primary key
    Port_Name varchar(30) -- unique
)

TblDeviceToPort
(
    DeviceToPort_Device int, -- fk to TblDevice
    DeviceToPort_Port int, -- fk to TblPort
    Primary key (DeviceToPort_Device, DeviceToPort_Port)
)
```